# Problems with fontspec and titlesec packages

Tags: xetex, fontspec, resume, titlesec

I've been trying to create a CV template by following the tutorial from [here](http://www.cv-templates.info/2009/03/professional-cv-latex/).

Here's the latex code I used

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}   %load fonts
\usepackage{url,parskip}   %formatting
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}  %other packages for XeTeX
\usepackage{titlesec}

%Graphics - Colors
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%better formatting of the A4 page
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}
%An alternative to Layaureo can be usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{supertabular}   %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}   %custom section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks, urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}

\titleformat{section}{Largescshaperaggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
```

I compiled it using XeTeX extension (xelatex resume.tex).

I got the following error message in the terminal.

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm Fontin
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation F for Fontin.
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Fontin
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf Fontin
! I can't find file `Fontin'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Fontin

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Fontin

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: Fontin.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Fontin' failed to make Fontin.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \zf@basefont=Fontin at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or install
ed font not found.
\zf@fontspec ...ntname \zf@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \unless \ifzf@icu \zf@set@...
l.26 ...[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
```

I suppose it's because the font 'Fontin' is missing. I downloaded 'Fontin' and tried to add it as external font by

```
\fontspec
[ Path = /home/primal/fonts/ ,
UprightFont = *-regular ,
BoldFont = *-bold ,
SmallCapsFont = *-SmallCaps ]
{Fontin}
```

But it didn't work out as well.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Also when I tried that line which was causing the error, I got an error message on next line specifying formatting for sections.

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `section' undefined in families `titlesec'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.28 ...section}{Largescshaperaggedright}{}{0em}{}
                                                  [\titlerule]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Problem has nothing to to with XeLateX or Fontin.

The reason for the error is that the `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` commands are incorrect. Apparently some backslashes got lost. If you look at Alessandro's complete source code in `cv.tex` or follow the link to his source, you will find that it should read

```
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
```

And by the way, you can also copy the Fontin files (or any other font for that matter) to your local OS font directory (`~/.fonts` in Linux) If all files are present there fontspec will automatically know which to use for bold etc.

Comment: Oh - and I left a comment on the original site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the packages from this site and install them individually....
http://www.josbuivenga.demon.nl/fontin.html