# XeLaTeX compilation of Alessandro Plasmati's CV example fails

Tags: xetex, miktex, fontspec, cv

I am trying to compose a CV of mine like this resource [link here](http://www.cv-templates.info/2009/03/professional-cv-latex/)!, but facing issues with compilations. Could you pls help me out?

Related known [question-in-stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7377/problems-with-fontspec-and-titlesec-packages).

1. On Win XP, MikTex 2.9 and TexWorks editor (exLateX already there)
2. I installed the required fonts and "fontspec" latest release
       (Feb 2011 version).
3. Trying to compile your tex file available on the site.
4. However, initially i faced the "expl3" error, which I was able to
   overcome by installing the two packages "l3kernel" and "l3packages".
5. Again, now I see this error...

**OUTPUT**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4 (MiKTeX 2.9)  
entering extended mode
(D:\Resume\resume_03.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese,
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\marvosym\marvosym.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3names.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3bootstrap.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def"))
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"))
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3basics.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3expan.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3tl.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3seq.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3int.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3quark.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3prg.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3clist.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3token.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3prop.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3msg.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3io.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3file.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3skip.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3keys.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3fp.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3box.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\xpackages\xcoffins\l3coffins.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"))
("D:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\tools\trace.sty")
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \filename
l.60 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}
?
```

Comment: Not knowing what the full command on l. 60 is, it's hard to start guessing what the cause of the breakdown is. Could you at least post a code snippet showing, say, lines 57 to 63, or your file. By the way, a few days ago a new version of fontspec -- 2.2 -- was released. You may want to keep an eye out for when miktex's updater program brings it to your system.

Comment: I guess that you've incurred in a rather common problem: somehow the latex3 packages on which **fontspec** relies are out of sync with your MiKTeX package manager. Synchronize with the server and all should go well. However I find that the CV in question has many weak points from a TeXnical point of view.

Comment: Hi, Thanks!! It can be found at the [link](http://aleplasmati.comuv.com/doc/cv.tex).

Comment: @egreg I will try synchronizing the packages. And can you through some more light on the Texnical aspects you were mentioning?

Comment: Some fonts are chosen with `\font` which is a Bad Thing; there are two mysterious `\setmainfont` declarations in the body, which are wrong. The overall structure is poorly programmed. I can see a `\large{...}\normalsize`, for example. As a starting point for a CV in may be good, surely not as a starting point for learning LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

Do make sure that your versions of fontspec and the l3* packages are fully up to date. The file cv.tex refers to a few fonts which you may or may not already have. The font `Fontin` can be downloaded free of charge from http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html; make sure to get the third variety, i.e., Opentype. (Ignore the part about the opentype being only for PCs.) There's also a watermark feature in the file cv.tex, which requires a font called `Baskerville`. I'd say that unless you already have that font (it's not free!), you can just comment out or delete that code segment (lines 45-55). With these adjustments made, I can't see why the file wouldn't compile on your system.

That said, I agree with egreg that the layout of the template isn't all that impressive. I certainly wouldn't use so much text in small-caps, for one. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Thanks eGreg!!
After sync-ing, I was able to compile without any errors!! (Hurrayyyy.. my resume will be ready in a day or two... :) )

Then, wrt Mico's point on the 'Baskervelle' font, yes, it gave an error! However, I changed it to Arial with success! 

Thanks everyone!!